# How do I add an element to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a services object that I need to append it's logs to where the ServiceLogEntries.ID equals the ServiceID.

```
var Services = {
            "result": [
                {
                    "ID": 150779,
                    "ServiceRenderedID": 1,
                    "ServiceTypeName": "Health Risk Assessment",
                    "PackageID": 13
                },
                {
                    "ID": 150778,
                    "ServiceRenderedID": 1,
                    "ServiceTypeName": "Health Risk Assessment",
                    "PackageID": 13
                }
            ]
        };

var ServiceLogEntries = {
            "ServiceLogEntries": [
                {
                    "LogID": 229500.0,
                    "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:29:16.137",
                    "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
                    "LogActionType": "I",
                    "ID": 150779
                },
                {
                    "LogID": 229501.0,
                    "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:30:07.32",
                    "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
                    "LogActionType": "U",
                    "ID": 150779
                },
                {
                    "LogID": 229500.0,
                    "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:29:16.137",
                    "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
                    "LogActionType": "I",
                    "ID": 150778
                },
                {
                    "LogID": 229501.0,
                    "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:30:07.32",
                    "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
                    "LogActionType": "U",
                    "ID": 150778
                }
            ]
        };
```

The result should look like the code below where the element "ServiceLogEntires" was created with it's corresponding items appended.

```
var Service = {
            "result": [
                {
                    "ID": 150779,
                    "ServiceRenderedID": 1,
                    "ServiceTypeName": "Health Risk Assessment",
                    "PackageID": 13
                },
                {
                    "ID": 150778,
                    "ServiceRenderedID": 1,
                    "ServiceTypeName": "Health Risk Assessment",
                    "PackageID": 13,
                    "ServiceLogEntries": [
                        {
                            "LogID": 229500.0,
                            "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:29:16.137",
                            "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
                            "LogActionType": "I",
                            "ID": 150778
                        },
                        {
                            "LogID": 229501.0,
                            "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:30:07.32",
                            "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
                            "LogActionType": "U",
                            "ID": 150778
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

I started looping through the objects which was easy enough but I need to get the whole element `"ServiceLogEntries": [{...}]`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Service.result.length; i++) {
            var parent = Service.result[i];
            for (var a = 0; a < ServiceLogEntries.ServiceLogEntries.length; a++) {
                var child = ServiceLogEntries.ServiceLogEntries[a];

                if (child.ID === parent.ID) {
                    parent.push(child);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: and what result do you get? do you know jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t3twxgfs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Services.result.forEach(function (service) {
    service.ServiceLogEntries = ServiceLogEntries.ServiceLogEntries.filter(function (entry) {
        return entry.ID === service.ID;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
$(function() {

  var Services = {
    "result": [{
      "ID": 150779,
      "ServiceRenderedID": 1,
      "ServiceTypeName": "Health Risk Assessment",
      "PackageID": 13
    }, {
      "ID": 150778,
      "ServiceRenderedID": 1,
      "ServiceTypeName": "Health Risk Assessment",
      "PackageID": 13
    }]
  };

  var ServiceLogEntries = {
    "ServiceLogEntries": [{
      "LogID": 229500.0,
      "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:29:16.137",
      "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
      "LogActionType": "I",
      "ID": 150779
    }, {
      "LogID": 229501.0,
      "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:30:07.32",
      "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
      "LogActionType": "U",
      "ID": 150779
    }, {
      "LogID": 229500.0,
      "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:29:16.137",
      "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
      "LogActionType": "I",
      "ID": 150778
    }, {
      "LogID": 229501.0,
      "LogStamp": "2015-12-08T18:30:07.32",
      "LogServerUser": "Webuser",
      "LogActionType": "U",
      "ID": 150778
    }]
  };

  $.each(Services.result, function(i, service) {
    service['ServiceLogEntries'] = ServiceLogEntries.ServiceLogEntries.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.ID === service.ID;  
    });
  })

  console.log(Services);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `.filter()` works by returning true or false, you can reduce it to `return elem.ID === service.ID;`.

Comment: oh thats true!! thanks... confused with map function

Comment: Also, `Services.result[i]` is the same as `service`. ;)

Comment: Simple oversights, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

You work with objects like dictionaries, not arrays, in javascript, so your loop becomes

```
for (var i = 0; i < Service.result.length; i++) {
            var parent = Service.result[i];
            for (var a = 0; a < ServiceLogEntries.ServiceLogEntries.length; a++) {
                var child = ServiceLogEntries.ServiceLogEntries[a];

                if (child.ID === parent.ID) {
                    parent.ServiceLogEntries = child;
                }
            }
        }
```